# The terminal runs outside the IDE in IntellijIDEA community edition 2018.1

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, ide, settings, intellij-idea-2018

I used to have the terminal embedded in my IntelliJ IDE but after I updated, whenever I click on the terminal icon, it runs externally in a separate window.

I don't remember having this issue in the previous version of IntelliJ. What configurations do I need to change to make it run inside the IDE?
[a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h39iY.png)

Comment: What executable did you configure as the terminal in the IDE settings?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm using git-bash.exe (C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe)

Comment: Did you try `c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Terminal, click on the cogwheel on the top right and make sure it's not set to float.

> UPDATE

Try following configuration.

[image]

Comment: The floating mode isn't on. Please checkout the screenshot I just added.

Comment: Yes I have all these checked. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: So the only difference in mine is I'm using 2017.3. Try rolling back to verify if there's a bug in new version.

Comment: I tried rolling back as you suggested but it didn't work either